# Understanding the Spanish verb tense chart

Tags: verbos, españa, tiempos-verbales, español-neutral

I lived in Spain for five years, however I only learnt Spanish by copying sentences as opposed to learning all of the grammatical rules from a book. I also had to memorise all of the Los Tiempos Verbales from my school book Lengua Castellana. Whilst I could pass the exams, and communicate roughly in my day-to-day life, I had little understanding of which verb tenses to use and when.

This left me in a position where I knew lots of different words, the difference between masculine and feminine, formal and informal, but I frequently used the wrong verb conjugations.

I came across [this](https://www.wordreference.com/conj/esverbs.aspx?v=comer) useful website for verb conjugations.

[image: Comer conjugations]

**Questions:**

1. Could someone tell me when I should use each of the headers: indicativo, formas compuestas comunes, subjuntivo, tiempos compuestos del subjuntivo, imperativo, and indicativo?
2. Then when I should use each of the subcategories, like why use indicativo's presente instead of the subjuntivo's presente.

My question is just for Spanish spoken in Spain, not Latino Spanish which I can focus on another time.

Comment: The main difference between *estaBa* and *estuVe* is clearly visible 

Comment: @Danielillo Updated my post, well spotted.

Comment: I reworded my question. I feel that there are a lot of cheat sheets online to memorise the conjugations, but nobody has clearly explained what each header means, and which category to use.

Comment: That is a really broad question. There is scope to write a whole book about the difference between indicative and subjunctive for instance. It might be better if you narrowed it down but beware that most of these issues have already been asked and answered on this site.

Comment: I agree with you: the question is very interesting, but at the same time I think that to make things good, the answer would be abnormally long.

Comment: You have to buy yourself one of those great Spanish grammar with graduated exercises. We can't possibly answer this here. It would be like explaining the uses of all verb forms in English.

Comment: Well, you could just write a sentence with the rule of thumb.

Comment: What research have you done so far on these topics?  In some instances, usage is = to usage in English. The internet is awash with grammar lessons/usage explanations eg https://grammar.spanishintexas.org/verbs/tense-mood/ and https://notesinspanish.com/files/NIS-Super-Simple-Subjunctive.pdf @Lambie is correct - if you want to understand fully, study a grammar book, there are no short cuts (especially where the subjunctive is concerned) IMHO

Comment: I think this is my biggest problem with learning Spanish. After learning the alphabet, sentences, masculine vs feminine, formal vs informal, the yo/tu/el/nosotros/vosotros/ellos, infinitives, and the present tense conjugations we are left in the middle of the ocean without a paddle when it comes to the other tiempos verbales. Most sources just list them like that website did, or explain individual ones. There should be a website which covers the general rule of thumb for each one...

Comment: Try https://www.lawlessspanish.com/tag/tenses-moods-voices/

Comment: @Traveller I *think* that was exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: @Traveller In my image above, where is the Conditional Progressive and Future Progressive? I read about them in the link, but cannot see in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

Desde mi punto de vista, si estas en España, lo que mejor puedes hacer es programar tu tiempo para dejar espacio y tomar clases de Español, eso ayuda a encontrar personas de otros países y practicar dentro y fuera de las clases.

En internet también tienes webs que te pueden ayudar, la lectura infantil aunque parezca paradójico hace maravillas y youtube esta lleno de videos interesantes, solo tienes que aprovechar la oportunidad.

---

Te dejo varias páginas de distintos tipos;

**Pretérito pluscuamperfecto**

*Indica una acción ocurrida con anterioridad a otra acción también pasada, es decir que ocurrida con anterioridad a otro tiempo pretérito. Ej: Cuando llegó Juan, ya habíamos comido*.

*Es un tiempo verbal compuesto, se forma con el verbo auxiliar «haber» en pretérito imperfecto y el participio del verbo principal*.

AMAR    TEMER    PARTIR

Yo  había amado había temido    había partido

Tú  habías amado    habías temido   habías partido

Él / Ella   había amado había temido    había partido

Nosotros / Nosotras habíamos amado  habíamos temido habíamos partido

Vosotros / Vosotras habíais amado   habíais temido  habíais partido

Ellos / Ellas   habían amado    habían temido   habían partido

---

**Pretérito anterior**

Se utiliza para hablar de una acción inmediatamente anterior a otra acción también pasada. Ej: Después que hubimos comido, salimos con Juan. Es un tiempo verbal que ha caído en desuso, y suele ser reemplazado por otros tiempos que puedan ser equivalentes en el contexto. Es un tiempo verbal compuesto, se forma con el verbo auxiliar «haber» en pretérito indefinido y el participio del verbo principal.

```
AMAR    TEMER    PARTIR
```

Yo  hube amado  hube temido hube partido

Tú  hubiste amado   hubiste temido  hubiste partido

Él / Ella   hubo amado  hubo temido hubo partido

Nosotros / Nosotras hubimos amado   hubimos temido  hubimos partido

Vosotros / Vosotras hubisteis amado hubisteis temido    hubisteis partido

Ellos / Ellas   hubieron amado  hubieron temido hubieron partido

---

etc

**https://www.pequeocio.com/tiempos-verbales/#que-son-los-tiempos-verbales**

---

Otra página web tipo;

La información sobre el uso de los modos y tiempos verbales en español ahora se explica por modo: indicativo, subjuntivo, condicional y imperativo. Lee también sobre el uso del infinitivo, el gerundio y el participio en español en el artículo sobre las formas verbales no personales.

**Presente**

Se utiliza para expresar acciones que tienen lugar en el momento en que se habla. Por ejemplo:

Juanita canta una canción.

Se utiliza para expresar acciones que ocurren frecuentemente. Por ejemplo:

Lydia nunca desayuna por la mañana.

Se puede utilizar para expresar acciones futuras. Por ejemplo:

El verano que viene mis amigos se van de vacaciones a los Estados Unidos.

Se utiliza para expresar órdenes. Por ejemplo:

Ahora mismo vas a casa de José y traes el libro.

Se puede utilizar para referirse a acciones pasadas. Por ejemplo:

Ayer estaba con Carlitos en el parque y de pronto viene Carla y me dice: ¿A quién esperas?

**Pretérito imperfecto**

Se utiliza para describir una acción que se desarrolla en el pasado, sin indicar si ha finalizado o no, mientras que el pretérito perfecto nos dice que la acción ya ha concluido. Por ejemplo:

<>

Se utiliza para hablar de acciones habituales del pasado. Por ejemplo:

Pepe leía muchos tebeos cuando era pequeño.

Se utiliza para dar detalles, como: tiempo, ubicación, hora, años, sentimientos, características mentales y físicas.

Hacía frío durante la noche.

**Pretérito indefinido**

Se llama también pretérito perfecto simple.

Se utiliza para hablar de hechos pasados. Siempre son acciones terminadas.

¿Qué pasó?

Suelen utilizarse las siguientes expresiones temporales con el pretérito indefinido: ayer, anteayer, anoche, una vez, dos veces, la semana pasada, etc.

Mi hermano llegó ayer.

Se puede encontrar el pretérito indefinido y el imperfecto en la misma frase.

Cuando navegábamos el domingo pasado nos cayó un chaparrón enorme.

**Futuro**

Se utiliza para hablar de acciones posteriores al tiempo en que se habla.
Siempre existe una dosis de incertidumbre. Nunca se puede estar seguro de la realización de la acción descrita. Por ejemplo:

La próxima semana lo escribiré.

El tiempo futuro se utiliza también para expresar...

...especulaciones del tiempo presente:

¿Qué hora será?

...una probabilidad del tiempo presente:

Serán las cuatro.

...una citación indirecta:

Elena dice que vendrá la semana que viene

**https://www.esfacil.eu/es/verbos/3-modos-y-tiempos-verbales-en-espanol.html**

---

Otra página de Recursos gratis para aprender Español

**https://svfspanish.com/14-recursos-para-aprender-espanol-y-practicar-gratis/**

---

Youtube

Los Tiempos Verbales en Español (1). Los Tiempos Simples.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQWeiD45EHo

Magical Spanish

Puedes activar los subtítulos para leer o disminuir la velocidad de reproducción para entenderlo mejor. Aunque tiene acento Americano, te explican bien los tiempos y algunos ejemplos de utilización. Espero te haya servido. Saludos.